# TypeError: userDB is not a constructor

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js, mysql2

I am creating a crud application, using nodejs sequelize express and xammp as by DB, I have managed to create a connection and seed some dummy data. I managed to create an API but when i tries to create data via postman i get this error 'TypeError: userDB is not a constructor'

I have attached my code here, Kindly an help on how to solve this

```
controller code


   const userDB = require('../models/user');
//create and save new user
exports.create =(req, res)=>{
 //validate request
 if(!req.body){
  res.status(400).send({
   message:"Content can not be empty!"
  });
  return;
 }
 //create new user
 const user =new userDB({
  name:req.body.name,
  email:req.body.email,
  gender:req.body.gender,
  status:req.body.status
 })
//save user in the database

user
.save(user)
.then(data=>{
 res.send(data)
})
.catch(err=>{
 res.status(500).send({
  message:err.message ||"Something went wrong while creating new user"
 });
});

}


my model
'use strict';
const {
  Model
} = require('sequelize');
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class User extends Model {
    /**
     * Helper method for defining associations.
     * This method is not a part of Sequelize lifecycle.
     * The `models/index` file will call this method automatically.
     */
    static associate(models) {
      // define association here
    }
  };
  User.init({
    name: DataTypes.STRING,
    email: DataTypes.STRING,
    gender: DataTypes.STRING,
    status: DataTypes.STRING
  }, {
    sequelize,
    modelName: 'User',
  });
  return User;
};


   my routes

     const express = require('express');
 const router = express.Router();
 const services = require('../services/render');

 const controller = require('../../controller/controllers');

 /**
  * @description Root Route
  * @methodGET
  */
 router.get('/', services.homeRoutes)

 /**
  * @description Root Route
  * @methodGET /add users
  */
router.get('/add-user',services.addUsers)

 /**
  * @description Root Route
  * @methodGET /update users
  */
router.get('/update-user', services.updateUsers)

//API
router.post('/api/users',controller.create);
router.get('/api/users',controller.find);
router.put('/api/users/:id',controller.update);
router.delete('/api/users/:id',controller.delete);

module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 0):

I was supposed to change this line of controller

```
  const userDB = require('../models/user');
```

to

```
  const userDB = require('../models/index');
```